# Dygraphs div not visible until browser Inspection window opened

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dygraphs

I've used dygraphs for a while and have never came across this issue. This has plagued me for a week, so I had to come to SO. (Forgive the URL, it's a dev server). http://104.131.112.188/dev/inputModal.php

If you go to that link, click the "Run Simulation" button, a bootstrap modal will appear. Inside it should be a dygraphs div, and it's there but appears blank.  I noticed that if I do Ctrl+Shift+I to open the browser inspector/console, suddenly the data appears. This is in Firefox/Chrome.

This does not happen if I move the div outside of this modal, and I can't figure it out. Thoughts?

Comment: you can trigger the resize event of the graph by jquery. i also had the same problem with graphs, it was solved by triggering the resize event manually after the loading of map(in your case graph).

Comment: Where did you put the resize call? Right after creating the dygraph object? That didn't work for me.  Doing g.resize() in the console does display the graph, so we're on the right track...

Comment: If you're getting your data via AJAX, you might be happier if you put the `resize` call in a `ready` handler, e.g. `g.ready(function() { g.resize(); })`.

Comment: The data is coming from a Javascript object, as part of a simulation based on form inputs. So, I'm still not 100% where I can put the resize call.  Order if operations is: Click button > run simulation > dynamically create graph div > construct dataset and display.

Comment: Is it possible that because I'm dynamically creating the div in javascript, that .ready() won't work, and/or that is the reason I'm having issues?  I'm creating the divs that way because I'm going to have multiple tabs inside of a modal each with a graph.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm this method below works for me. Thanks to all.

```
<script>
    var graph = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphPanel"), "temperatures.csv", {
        animatedZooms: true
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        graph.resize(800, 500)
    });
</scrip>
```